Chemical potentials in a pair creation process
Consider the process of creation and annihilation of electron/positron pairs:
$ e^- + e^+ \rightleftharpoons 2 \gamma$.
The equilibrium condition for this system is $\mu_- + \mu_+ = 2\mu_\gamma$. The chemical potential of the photons is taken to be zero because its number is not conserved. Based on this, how can I rigorously compute the chemical potential of the electrons and positrons?
I have found two arguments, but neither of them are sufficiently rigurous. The first one is to argue that, since electrons and positrons are not conserved, their chemical potential is zero. The issue I see with this argument is that it completely neglects the equilibrium condition of the system. In reality, there is a conservation law in the system (number of electrons = number of positrons), whereas simply taking $\mu_\pm = 0$ assumes that electrons can be created independently of the number of positrons.
The second argument is to impose that $\langle n_+\rangle = \langle n_- \rangle$, and from this to equate the Fermi-Dirac distributions:
$$
\frac1{e^{-\beta(\epsilon-\mu_+)}+1} = \frac1{e^{-\beta(\epsilon-\mu_-)}+1} ,
$$
which implies that $\mu_+=\mu_-=0$. The problem with this derivation is that, even assuming $\langle n_+\rangle = \langle n_- \rangle$ (which seems to depend on the initial number of particles of the systems), equating the Fermi-Dirac distributions assumes that the populations of electrons and positrons are equal in all levels. But, in principle, there is no physical law forbidding electrons to populate higher levels than positrons. It is counterintuitive for this to happen, yes, but I cannot find a law that prohibits it.
So, to sum up, my question is: how to get $\mu_+=\mu_-=0$ using only rigurous physical arguments?
